# Synchronizing infinitely looped service's initialization part

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization

I'm trying to implement a piece of code to synchronously start looped service in Java. The idea is, code under `// STARTER` comment should be considered as piece of `Service.go()` method, so if service fails to start, I want to re-throw the exception synchronously. That piece of code should only finish in case I've **tried** to start the thread, waited until its execution flow reached some point and next, if there are no problems, my `go()` method quits and thread goes on, or, if there were problems, I can re-throw the exception caught in thread's `run()` method from my go() method. Here's the solution that seems to work fine, but I'm curious if it's possible to make it a couple times shorter :-)

```
public class Program {

private static boolean started;
private static Throwable throwable;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Object startedSetterLock = new Object();

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.printf("trying to start...\n");

            boolean ok;
            Throwable t = null;
            try {
                init();
                ok = true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                ok = false;
                t = e;
            }

            synchronized(startedSetterLock) {
                started = ok;
                throwable = t;
                startedSetterLock.notifyAll();
            }

            if(!ok) {
                return;
            }

            while(true) {
                try {
                    System.out.printf("working...\n");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.printf("interrupted\n");
                }                   
            }
        }

        private void init() throws Exception { throw new Exception(); } // may throw
    };

            // STARTER
    synchronized(startedSetterLock) {
        thread.start();
        try {           
            startedSetterLock.wait();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.printf("interrupted\n");
        }
    }       

    // here I'm 100% sure that service has either started or failed to start
    System.out.printf("service started: %b\n", started);
    if(!started) {
        throwable.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And also, there's a **reason** to have initialization code executed within that thread, so, please, don't advise running initialization code explicitly in `go()` method and then just passing all the stuff to the thread.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about overriding the `Thread.start()` method?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                try {
                    System.out.printf("working...\n");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.printf("interrupted\n");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public synchronized void start() {
            try {
                init();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            super.start();
        }

        private void init() throws Exception {
            throw new Exception("test");
        }
    };

    t.start();
}
```

Comment: Thread.start() is executed within caller's thread, I believe.

Comment: Indeed. Then i guess you'll have to wait on a common lock.